# Return value of string

Tags: javascript, string, methods

I have the string `format`, which contains the numbers {0}, {1}, {2}. And I want this numbers to be replaced by the words written from the placeholder in the input type `placeholder = "Outside,beautiful,blue"`, i.e. the value of `format[i+1]` be equal to index of the string `words`(contains the words in placeholder). And in the console as a result to get something like this:

Outside is so beautiful with blue sky, beautiful nature and house next to the blue pacific ocean...

HTML:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Exercises in JS</title>
        <script src="exercises.js"></script>
    <body>
        <label for="myText">Input array:</label>
            <input type="text" name="wordcount" id="myText" placeholder = "Outside,beautiful,blue" value="" />
        <a href="#" id="sub">Submit</a>
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Javacript code:

```
window.onload = function(){

inputBox = document.getElementById("myText");
btn = document.getElementById('sub');   

btn.addEventListener("click",function(event){
event.preventDefault();
    stringFormat(inputBox.value);   
});

    str = inputBox.value;
    var format = '{0} is so {1} with {2} sky, {1} nature and house next to the {2} pacific ocean...';

    function stringFormat(str) {
        var words = document.getElementById("myText").placeholder.split(",");

        for (var i = 0; i < format.length; i++) {
            if (format[i] === '{' && format[i+1] == '0') {
                format = format.replace(format[i+1], words[i]);        
            }

            else if (format[i] === '{' && format[i+1] > '0') {
                format = format.replace(format[i+1], words['$[i]']);
            }
        }
        console.log(format);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't loop though the input string, loop through the words array instead and just replace "{" + i + "}" each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Loop through the placeholders in the string, retrieving the equivalent word. This is really easy to do with `String#replace`'s callback function and a regular expression.
2. Loop through the words and use individual operations to replace `"{" + indexOfWord + "}"` with the relevant word.

I'd use #1, which looks like this:

```
function stringFormat(str, words) {
    return str.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(m, c0) {
        return words[c0] || "";
    });
}
```

Details:

- The regular expression `/\{(\d+)}/` looks for the pattern `{n}` where `n` is a number, and captures the `n` in a capture group.
- `replace` calls its callback function with an argument for the overall match it found (so, for instance, `"{0}"`) followed by the value of any capture groups. Since we have a capture group around the digits, the second argument we get will be just those digits, e.g. `"0"`.
- We use that to index into the array of `words` (remember, array indexes aren't really numbers because arrays [aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), it's fine that we're using a string) to look up the equivalent word.
- In case there's a placeholder that doesn't have a matching word, we use the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to get `""` if `words[c0]` is `undefined`.
- We return the string we want used for each replacement, which `replace` puts in the result string for us.

*(Both links above are to my anemic little blog.)*

Example:

```js
function stringFormat(str, words) {
  return str.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(m, c0) {
    return words[c0] || "";
  });
}

console.log(
  stringFormat(
    "{0} is so {1} with {2} sky, {1} nature and house next to the {2} pacific ocean...",
    "Outside,beautiful,blue".split(",")
  )
);
```

But if you prefer #2, it's also entirely feasible; you still have to use a regular expression in order to replace all of the placeholders:

```
function stringFormat(str, words) {
    words.forEach(function(word, index) {
        // (Have to escape `{` because it's a quantifier)
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + index + "}", "g"), word);
    });
    return str;
}
```

In that example, we have to escape `{` because it has special meaning in regular expressions. (We could also escape `}`, but we don't have to; it only has special meaning when it's in a pair with an unescaped `{`.)

Example:

```js
function stringFormat(str, words) {
  words.forEach(function(word, index) {
    // (Have to escape `{` because it's a quantifier)
    str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + index + "}", "g"), word);
  });
  return str;
}

console.log(
  stringFormat(
    "{0} is so {1} with {2} sky, {1} nature and house next to the {2} pacific ocean...",
    "Outside,beautiful,blue".split(",")
  )
);
```

**but** you'll want to escape any characters in `word` that are special in regular expressions, should there be any (I didn't bother above), and it requires multiple passes through the string. So on the whole, #1.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! But I don't get all the things you uses - we escape only '{' but we don't escape '}' and how he know which is the index and get back the right word ?

Comment: @Santiya: Sorry about that, I've beefed up the explanations above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the deepest explanation! Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for regular expressions:

```js
str = "{0} is so {1} with {2} sky, {1} nature and house next to the {2} pacific ocean..."

words = 'Outside,beautiful,blue'.split(',')

result = str.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, m => words[m[1]]);

console.log(result)
```

Without regexes, it would be a one-liner either:

```js
str = "{0} is so {1} with {2} sky, {1} nature and house next to the {2} pacific ocean..."

words = 'Outside,beautiful,blue'.split(',')

result = words.reduce((str, word, n) => str.split('{' + n + '}').join(word), str);

console.log(result)
```